# sharedPreferences in listView

Tags: java, android, listview, sharedpreferences

i want to get an array from an array in sharefPreferenc but it can not recover values ! plz see my code and tell me what is wrong ?!

this is my Prefs.java

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Random rnd = new Random();

    int[] cartridgeColor = new int[181];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 180; i++) {
        int aaa = rnd.nextInt(13);
        String name = "cartridgeColor" + String.valueOf(i);
        cartridgeColor[i] = prefs.getInt(name, aaa);
    }

}

}
```

and this is my activity wich wants to get from prefs

```
public class GamesListActivity extends ListActivity {

SharedPreferences sp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.games_list);
    setListAdapter(new AA());
    sp = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

}


class AA extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public AA() {
        super(GamesListActivity.this, R.layout.games_list_layout, Resources2.GameListArray);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.games_list_layout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView GameName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView GamePic = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ImageView Cartridge = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        int[] CartridgesColorArray = new int[181];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 180; i++) {

            String name = "cartridgeColor" + String.valueOf(i);
            CartridgesColorArray[i] = (sp.getInt(name, 1));

        }

        GameName.setText(Resources2.GameListArray[position]);
        GamePic.setImageResource(Resources2.GamePicArray[position]);
        Cartridge.setImageResource(Resources2.CartridgeFrame[CartridgesColorArray[position]]);

        return row;

    }
}
```

}

and this is my other class

```
public class Resources2 {

public static String[] GameListArray  = { "Super Mario Bros1", "Battle City", "Contra", "TinyTon", "Tmnt3 Manhattan Project" };
public static int[]    GamePicArray   = { R.drawable.g1, R.drawable.g2, R.drawable.g3, R.drawable.g4, R.drawable.g5 };
public static int[]    CartridgeFrame = { R.drawable.micro_cart_01, R.drawable.micro_cart_02, R.drawable.micro_cart_03, R.drawable.micro_cart_04, R.drawable.micro_cart_05, R.drawable.micro_cart_06, R.drawable.micro_cart_07, R.drawable.micro_cart_09, R.drawable.micro_cart_10, R.drawable.micro_cart_11, R.drawable.micro_cart_12, R.drawable.micro_cart_01, R.drawable.micro_cart_01, R.drawable.micro_cart_01 };

}
```

all things is ok and no any Error !

Answer (score 0):

I spot two things wrong with the code snippets above.

I don't see any writing to SharedPreferences. You should go read up on the [SharedPreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

Assuming you're doing that already, you need to make sure you're reading and writing to the same file. `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)` and `getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE)` do *not* point to the same file, so you'll need to correct that.

Some additional tips:

- It's good practice to reuse objects or values that should be identical. Consider having one method that creates a SharedPreferences object so you're certain you're always reading/writing to the same file.
- I'd consider using Gson to write out objects or collections to SharedPreferences, instead of making an entry for each. It would greatly simply things.